# Avoiding errors on Access name-parsing query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to clean up data in an older database, and the FirstName field has been polluted with middle names & initials over the years. Using a simple Left-Mid query, I'm easily able to split the names on a space. But I'm running into problems when I try to avoid returning an #ERROR on the entries that actually have just a first name.

I tried using NULLIF. The idea was that if there were no spaces in the name, return NULL as the middle name and pass the entire string to FName.

```
SELECT MID([FirstName], NULLIF(INSTR([FirstName], " "), 0) AS [MName],
LEFT([FirstName], ISNULL(NULLIF(INSTR([FirstName], " "), 0),
LEN([FirstName])) AS [FName]
FROM Persons;
```

I also tried using an IIF statement - if there is a space in the name, then parse it, else return the MName as null.

In both instances, Access returns a Syntax error (missing operator). The basic Left-Mid query works on its own, and I can pass a WHERE to just grab the entries where there is a space. Am I just forgetting something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    IIF(INSTR(FirstName," ")>0, MID(FirstName, INSTR(FirstName," ")), null) AS MName,
    LEFT(FirstName, IIF(INSTR(FirstName," ")>0, INSTR(FirstName," "), LEN(FirstName))) AS FName
FROM 
    Persons;
```

Honestly, I never heard about `NULLIF`. I just googled it and I only found SQL Server references.
Are you sure that's available in MS Access?
*(I have to admit - I can only try on A2000 now, because that's the only version I have installed on this machine)*

Comment: Sorry - neglected to answer the second part of your question. I think NULLIF will work in Access 2007, but I'm not entirely sure. I guess when I used it before it was on SQL Server.

Comment: IfNull() exists in other SQL dialects, but not in Jet/ACE/Access.